# Cannot plot with Gadfly when running script with `julia -i`

Tags: plot, julia, interactive, gadfly

When running `julia` REPL from the command line and copy-pasting my script, the Gadfly `plot` command works as expected.

But, when running `julia -i scriptname.jl` `plot` no longer works and prints:

```
julia> DataFrame(CSV.File("file.csv"))
julia> plot(massdf, x=:date, y=:mass, group=:day, color=:day, Geom.line)
Plot(...)

julia>
```

Is there a setting needed to make it work?

Comment: Can you share the script? It might have to do with if you are explicitly displaying the image and such.

Comment: @logankilpatrick I have added details from my script. I just use the default which when run in the straight REPL open a browser and display hmtl + SVG.

Comment: As @logankilpatrick suggested, you need to explicitly display the output of `plot()` in your script (which is done implicitly in a Read-Eval-**Print**-Loop but not when the whole script is executed, even with `-i`). Use `display(p::Plot)`, or `draw(backend::Compose.Backend, p::Plot)`.

Comment: @EricLavault Could you please add that as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly display the output of `plot()` in your script (which is done implicitly in a Read-Eval-**Print**-Loop but not when the whole script is executed, even with `-i`).

Use [`display(p::Plot)`](http://gadflyjl.org/stable/lib/gadfly/#Base.Multimedia.display-Tuple%7BGadfly.GadflyDisplay,%20Union%7BContext,%20Plot%7D%7D), or [`draw(backend::Compose.Backend, p::Plot)`](http://gadflyjl.org/stable/lib/gadfly/#Compose.draw-Tuple%7BCompose.Backend,%20Plot%7D) :

```
df = DataFrame(CSV.File("file.csv"))
p = plot(df, x=:date, y=:mass, group=:day, color=:day, Geom.line)
display(p)
```

See also Gadfly [Backends](http://%20http://gadflyjl.org/stable/man/backends/).

Comment: I tried both "display(p)" and "display(p::Plot)" and get the same result: "Plot(...)".